# Android Browser not consistently return json from ajax call

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, android-browser

I'm making an ajax call that repeatedly calls an api for json data. I've never had it fail with other browsers, but something weird is happening to the response within the Android Browser. I put a console log using weinre that catches the returned data. Can anyone make sense of it and how to handle it?

Screenshot:
[image]

Everything is running along smoothly until the last one causes an error like this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Requests' of undefined`

Why is it not returning like the previous json return from the ajax calls?

Comment: At some point batch is clearly undefined, so when it tries to read your Requests property it fails.  Hard to know anything else without seeing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anyway to handle this other than wrap the whole result in a try catch. If it does catch something then it just tries again to get the batch and has thus far always been successful on the second attempt.

```
try {
//ajax returned result
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        getBatch();
    }, 2000);
}
```